# Vscode opening files with error instead of showing error message in debug console

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, runtime-error

I am working with Flutter and when an exception is thrown, the error message is not shown in the debug console, rather the file which has the error message is opened. This is disturbing considering the opened files are core parts of the Dart language and the Flutter framework. When accidentally edited, they can cause severe problems in how they work. Additionally, when the files are opened just like that, you are not able to determine exactly where in your code the error emanated or why the error is showing, sometimes it's just a file with code you don't understand. So is there anything I can do to ensure the files are not opened abruptly or at least a way to ensure that files outside my project can't be edited or I'm given a notice when I try to do so?

TL;DR: Vscode opens files which have an error or error message instead of showing in debug console.

Comment: i have similar problem idk why this is happening

Answer (score 1):

When an exception occurs, the debugger pauses and navigates to the location of the exception to help you debug the issue.

In the status bar there should be some text that says something like "Debug my code" or "Debug my code + sdk + packages". If you set this to just "Debug my code" (which is the default) it should no longer jump into SDK/package code, but instead the first stack frame inside your own code.

Other options if you don't want the debugger to pause like this at all, and only want exceptions printed to the debug console:

- use "Run"/"Run without Debugging" instead of "Debug"
- untick the "Break on exceptions" options at the bottom of the debug sidebar